# Squared Equation calculator not working in C

Tags: c

Hello guys I started learning C few weeks ago and I am trying to make my first useful program, I am trying to create a squared equation calculator but no matter what I type in the input it always outputs "no solution2" can anyone take a look and help me ? 
examples for input :
 0 0 0= [image]
 1 4 1= [image]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
int main()
{
    printf("enter a\n");
    double a; scanf("%1f", &a);
    printf("\nenter b\n");
    double b; scanf("%1f", &b);
    printf("\nenter c\n");
    double c; scanf("%1f", &c);
    if (a==0)
    {
        if (b==0)
        {
            if (c==0)
                printf("x can be every number\n");
            else
                printf("no solution1\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("x equals %.2f\n", ((-1)*c) / b);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        double delta = (b*b)-(4*(a*c));
        if (delta>0)
        {
            double sqrtDlt = sqrt(delta);
            printf("x1 = %4.2f\n", (((-1)*b) + sqrtDlt) / 2 * a);
            printf("x2 = %4.2f\n", (((-1)*b) - sqrtDlt) / 2 * a);
        }
        else
            printf("no solution2\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For debugging a first step would be to trace which if/else branches the code follows for different input. Likewise, print the variables you entered on the screen to see if the are how you expect them to be,.

Comment: `scanf("%1f", &a);` ==> `scanf("%lf", &a);` (change the numeral "one" to the letter "ell"). You are asking for `float` but the variable is `double`.

Comment: Please also change `if (delta>0)` to `if (delta>=0)`since `sqrt(0)` is valid.

Comment: Your formula is incorrect: `(((-1)*b) + sqrtDlt) / 2 * a` should be `(-b + sqrtDlt) / (2 * a)`.

Comment: Also, always check return value of `scanf` (and if it is not what you expect, you need to handle that somehow, in a toy/learning programs for example by just exiting with error message).

Comment: Also: please don't post images of text.

Comment: @mch the -1*b is the same , about the (2*a) you are right fixed it@phillipD&@weather vane thx guys  its working now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For double use specifier  `%l(ell)f` not `%1(one)f` in scanf.

*Note that* this is one place that `printf` format strings differ substantially from `scanf` (and fscanf, etc.) format strings. For output, you're passing a value, which will be promoted from `float` to `double` when passed as a variadic parameter. For input you're passing a `pointer`, which is not promoted, so you have to tell `scanf` whether you want to read a `float` or a `double`, **so for `scanf`, `%f` means you want to read a `float` and `%lf` means you want to read a `double`.**

Comment: Minor detail: `scanf()` does not read a `float` nor `double`.  `scanf()` reads text (characters) and converts/saves the results as `float`, `double`, etc.

Comment: @ShahrairNazimReal did so, but i have less than 15 reputation so you can't see it :)